# How to show validation error for inactive user with some response code

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am trying to build custom user model in django-rest-framework. The problem which i am facing is how should i show the custom message with response code when the user is not activate.

Currently if the user provided the correct credentials but the account is not active then he is throwing error response code 400 with the validation error. Here is my code which I am using for the login validation.

```
class TokenAuthSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
  email = serializers.CharField()
  password = serializers.CharField(
    style = {'input_type':'password'},
    trim_whitespace = False
  )

def validate(self,attrs):
    email = attrs.get('email')
    password = attrs.get('password')

    user = authenticate(
        request= self.context.get('request'),
        email = email,
        password = password
    )

    if not user:
        msg = _('Unable to authenticate with given credentials')
        raise serializers.ValidationError(msg, code = 'authorization')
    attrs['user'] = user
    return attrs
```

In views:

```
class CreateTokenAuthorization(ObtainAuthToken):
  serializer_class = TokenAuthSerializer
  renderer_classes = api_settings.DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES
```

How to override this method to get the proper response code for the user is not active. Thank you for looking over it.

Comment: can you please post your view for the same ?

Comment: @SukhpreetSingh I have updated my question. Please have a look

Comment: i 'll need to have a look at your `ObtainAuthToken` view in order to understand how the object is obtained.